# Bluetooth devices discovery and custom list adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, listadapter

I'm trying to retrieve a list of visible Bluetooth devices and pass gathered information to a ListView using custom adapter.
The only problematic part of my function is adding discovered items(devices) to a ListView, where while testing different approaches, either **ListView is not populated at all, items get overwritten or items become duplicate within ListView**.

My current function does not populate ListView at all:

```
public void startDevicesDiscovery(){

    rowItemsDevices.clear();
    devicesAdapter =new DevicesListAdapter(tContext, rowItemsDevices);

    //cancel discovery if discovering
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    general.log("BT","start list size: "+rowItemsDevices.size());
    bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            General general = new General(tContext);
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // if device found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                btDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if(btDevice == null){
                    general.log("BT","device NULL");
                }else{

                    Device device = new Device(btDevice.getName(),btDevice.getAddress());

                    general.log("BT","device: "+device.getDeviceName()+"\ndevice MAC: "+device.getMacAddress());

                    RowItemDevices items = new RowItemDevices(device.getDeviceName(),device.getMacAddress());
                    rowItemsDevices.add(items);
                    devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                general.log("BT","device search finished");
                general.log("BT","end list size: "+rowItemsDevices.size());
            }

        }
    };

    visibleDevices.setAdapter(devicesAdapter);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter);

    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

}
```

Logs show that devices were discovered correctly:
[image]

In order to exclude causes of the problem being in my custom ListView adapter itself, I created a test function which proves that adding elements to my ListView works correctly:

```
public void testListView(){
    general.log("BT","testListView");
    rowItemsDevices.clear();
    devicesAdapter =new DevicesListAdapter(tContext, rowItemsDevices);
    RowItemDevices items = new RowItemDevices("test 1","test sub 1");
    rowItemsDevices.add(items);
    RowItemDevices items2 = new RowItemDevices("test 2","test sub 2");
    rowItemsDevices.add(items2
    );
    visibleDevices.setAdapter(devicesAdapter);
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong here? It looks like function `startDevicesDiscovery` works as expected but maybe I am implementing it not the right way?

**EDIT:**

After adding `devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on my adapter, the list is showing correct values on first run, yet if I run the function again, the items become duplicate so that is the same problem I had at the beginning. By looking at the logs, I can see that the problem is cause by the BroadcastReceiver which, for some reason, on the second search, addz previously discovered devices to the new search. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: try calling `yourListView.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `rowItemsDevices.add(items);`. As far as I see, you don't tell your ListView that ther is some new data to display. It does not monitor your source collection automatically

Comment: It indeed helped refreshing the ListView, but the problem with duplicate items in it remains. Please see my edit

Comment: Looks like you just not unregister old receiver after scan finished. Try using this: `else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                general.log("BT","device search finished");
                general.log("BT","end list size: "+rowItemsDevices.size());
unregisterReceiver(this);//add this
            }`

Comment: Perfect, unregistering receiver did the job. Please add it as answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To make `ListView` show added items, you have to tell `ListVIew` that something is updated in it's list: add `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `rowItemsDevices.add(items);`. Without it `ListView` will newer know that he already has some items to draw.
2. The items now are duplicated because you register new `BroadcastReceiver`, and don't unregister the old one. If you try to run your method 3rd time, you will get 3-plicated items. So you have to unregister the receiver after scan finished:

   ```
   else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
       general.log("BT","device search finished");
       general.log("BT","end list size: "+rowItemsDevices.size());
       unregisterReceiver(this); //add this line
   }
   ```

Comment: One note, according to documentation notifyDataSetChanged should be called on adapter and not on the ListView

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki, yup, you're right. I just wrote the code not in IDE